# How to do auto input in multiple read-lines?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

How to do auto input in multiple read-line?

```
(let ((out (with-output-to-string (*standard-output*) 
                (let ((*standard-input* (make-string-input-stream "y y")))
                  (when (find (read-line) '("yes" "y" "t") :test #'string-equal)
                    (print "aaaaa"))
                  (when (find (read-line) '("yes" "y" "t") :test #'string-equal)
                    (print "bbbbbb"))
                  ))))
     out)
```

I try like this, and I get:

```
; Evaluation aborted on #<END-OF-FILE {10048FD503}>.
```

This code work with `read`, but I need with `read-line`.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to use the parameter of `read-line` that requires to return `nil` on end of file:

```
(let ((out (with-output-to-string (*standard-output*) 
        (let ((*standard-input* (make-string-input-stream "y y")))
          (when (find (read-line *standard-input* nil) '("yes" "y" "t") :test #'string-equal)
             (print "aaaaa"))
          (when (find (read-line *standard-input* nil) '("yes" "y" "t") :test #'string-equal)
             (print "bbbbbb"))))))
  out)
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it work like this:

```
(with-output-to-string (*standard-output*)
  (with-input-from-string (*standard-input* (format nil "y~%y"))
    (when (find (read-line) '("yes" "y" "t") :test #'string-equal)
      (print "aaaaa"))
    (when (find (read-line) '("yes" "y" "t") :test #'string-equal)
      (print "bbbbbb"))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `without-to-string` is unnecessary for an example...

```
CL-USER 177 > (flet ((yes-p (input-string &aux (yes-words '("yes" "y" "t")))
                       "returns T when the input-string is one of yes, y or t."
                       (find input-string yes-words :test #'string-equal)))
                (with-input-from-string (*standard-input* (format nil "y~%y"))
                  (when (yes-p (read-line))
                    (print "aaaaa"))
                  (when (yes-p (read-line))
                    (print "bbbbbb"))
                  (values)))

"aaaaa" 
"bbbbbb"
```